# android app with facebook login integrated, how to generate the release key?

Tags: android, facebook, publish, sign, release-mode

I have a problem when I want to publish my application android with fb integrated. I signed my app with eclipse, and used **"keytool -exportcert -alias androidreleasekey -keystore MyReleaseKeystore.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64"** in terminal to generate a release key, and I added in "Native Android App" configuration.

I tested l'app, and I got error when I wanted to login: " is misconfigured for facebook login.... "

When I tested with debugkey, all works well. 
And When I generate the release key for FB, the keytool didn't ask me for the password. I think it should have? 
is the "-alias androidreleasekey" should have a nother alias name? or juste whatever i like?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've checked all the steps, everything is correct. 
My problème appears just when app facebook is installed; when app facebook is not installed, everything works well.

I finished it by forcing all login FB by the browser, never by facebook app.

Thanks every one!

Comment: how did you force to login by the browser ??

Answer (score 1):

You must have given a wrong path to your keystore file, make sure your path is valid

as stated [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#sig) : General Rule: If the tool does not ask for password, your keystore path is incorrect.

about the alias i'm pretty sure you should write the same one as you signed your app with .. because i've seen a different key is generated with different alias.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these points and it's guaranteed to work:

1. Make sure the path to your keystore file is correct. The keytool command will generate a key even if the path is incorrect. How do you know it's correct? You are asked for a password.
2. The alias is critical. If you're not sure what the Alias is, export your apk once from within Eclipse (Right click project -> Android Tools -> Export signed application package). After you insert the password, you need to select an alias from the dropdown. Make sure this is exactly the same alias you should be using from the command line.
3. Copy the generated hash including the '=' sign at the end. and paste it to the facebook app console. Don't forget to click 'Save changes'.