# Android Facebook application crashes when using a hash key other than the debug hash key

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I developed an app which perfectly runs with the debug hash key. But when I use the apk generated with "Android Tools / Export Signed Application Package ..." under Eclipse it crashes.

As lined out under http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/ I show a Toast which presents the hash key. I add this key to the list of hash keys for my application. But that does not help.

I read [android app with facebook login integrated, how to generate the release key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12393860/android-app-with-facebook-login-integrated-how-to-generate-the-release-key) but found no answer.

Thank you in advance!
BR

Answer (score 0):

may be this link will help you i think your using signed apk to generate hashkey

[Signed APK has different Key-Hash for Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11864700/signed-apk-has-different-key-hash-for-facebook)

Comment: Thank you! I tried it again:

I set up a new Android project as described e. g. under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/.

I added both hash keys (debug and “normal”) to “Key Hashes” in the app setting under “developers.facebook.com”. I also toasted the keys in my app and verified that they are correct.

Result (again): Debug hash key works and “normal” hash key does not (i. e. app crashes)!

Can someone help me (as I become desperate)?

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: The onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) method IS called with my debug hash key but IS NOT called with my normal hash key (see https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RWqd8p8s8Cnb7FlPkBAAmzQrFlvLCbmNCp1w74eov6o/edit?pli=1). 
With with my normal hash key the app crashes instead.

Comment: Error message is:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 20:31:27.143: E/AndroidRuntime(9976): com.facebook.aa: com.facebook.c.e got an unexpected method signature: public abstract com.facebook.c.b com.facebook.c.b.a(java.lang.Class) ...

Comment: I just did the following test with my Eclipse environment running under Windows 7 (using Android Tools / Export Signed Application Package): I created the application with my debug keystore. As intended it shows the debug hash key BUT ALSO CRASHES!
Thus I suppose this issue is not a matter with the server side logic at Facebook but with my Eclipse tool chain!
Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I found that it was an issue with my proguard settings:
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../FacebookSDK
crashes and
# proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=../FacebookSDK
does not.
I will come up with news as soon as I fixed this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108397/android-facebook-connect-not-working-in-release-build shows the solution!

Comment: I am facing the same problem..have you fixed the issue?