# Signed apk crashes with facebook login

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

My Signed apk crashes first time on facebook login with this error:

AndroidRuntime: FATAL Exception: main
com.facebook.aq: com.facebook.c.f got an unexpected method signature: public abstract com.facebook.c.c com.facebook.c.c.a(java.lang.Class)

However, it works fine with 2nd attempt login. I am using Facebook-android-sdk-3.6.0.
I've checked here too - [Android Facebook application crashes when using a hash key other than the debug hash key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781633/android-facebook-application-crashes-when-using-a-hash-key-other-than-the-debug), but didn't find any solution.
Do anyone faced the same issue, please help me in sorting out the above problem.

Comment: please check your facebook hash key is same for signed apk.

Comment: nopes its different, coz the hash key is first generated through debug keystore and after signing up it has different keyhash with created keystore. But I've added all keyhashes to my app developer's console.

Comment: recreate apk with clean project.

Comment: I've done that too, but same result

Comment: @AmritPalSingh- did you fix that issue? Kindly help me.

Comment: @RahulRawat- yes I have solved it, it was issue with the hashkey only. I've to regenerate hash key again after signing app and put it on my facebook developer's console, have you checked whether your hash key generated after app signing is present on you facebook developer console.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're using proguard. Facebook SDK sources are open. No need to obfuscate them. We added this rule to our proguard.cfg file: -keep class com.facebook.** { *; }